# Visual Studio Code is changing HTML after saving (React)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, visual-studio

I started to  learn react. A few minutes later messed up. I was looking for a setting and somehow I come where else where i selected a different choice(something like NodeJS)...now my problem is:

First Image

[image]

Second Image

[image]

First image is what I wrote. Second image is what it became after saving(CTRL + S).

Third Image
[image]
This third image is the changed original template...

I tried to reinstall VS Code and deleting the settings(user/json) file nothing has changed. Does anyone know how to fix this problem.

Any help is appreciated :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

On the status bar of VS Code, you would see the language that has been set automatically to your file
[where to find the language mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVLtX.png)

click on the name of the language and it would take you to this section[language mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq3F5.png)

Type the language you want to use for that first and select it or
You can select configure file association for '...' and type the language you want to use.(This changes the language forever unless you decide to change it)

Answer (score 0):

I got that error too try renaming `js` files to `jsx` or
[image]
[image]

Comment: Actually this was the setting i was looking for, thank you. What's the error ?

Comment: Don't know but did it work?

Comment: oh sry didn't see 'that error ' ....it just worked for me. I selected html,python... for tring. As last JavaScript React and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

their is different formatter for react. but for instant fix just disable auto formating on save from vscode setting.

[image]